# Wolfram script produces no output

Tags: scripting, mac-os-x

I use Mathematica to create a series of PNG images in a for loop. I want to execute the notebook from the command line in macOS. I exported it as a wolframscript -- see below -- but nothing happens when I execute the script using `wolframscript`.

````
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Input:: *)
(*fps=60;*)
(*dur=4;*)
(*tmin=0;*)
(*tmax = 8*Pi;*)
(*A=-0.125;*)
(*B=0.003;*)
(*name = surface_deformation;*)
(*For[i=0,i<=fps*dur,i++,*)
(*t=tmin+(tmax-tmin)/(fps*dur)*i;*)
(*surface=ParametricPlot3D[{-2*x*(Sin[t]*A*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/B]-1)/(x^2+y^2+1),-2*y*(Sin[t]*A*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/B]-1)/(x^2+y^2+1),(x^2+y^2-1)*(Sin[t]*A*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/B]-1)/(x^2+y^2+1)},{x,-0.2,0.2},{y,-0.2,0.2},PlotRange->{{-0.5,0.5},{-0.5,0.5},{0.8,1.2}},Boxed->False,Axes->False,ImageSize->{640,480},PlotStyle->"BlueGreenYellow"];*)
(*Export["~/Movies/mathematica/"<>ToString[name]<>"/"<>ToString[name]<>"-"<>ToString[i]<>".png",Show[surface],Background->None]*)
(*]*)


(* ::Input:: *)
(**)


(* ::Input:: *)
(**)

```
````

Comment: Every line that begins with `(*` and ends with `*)` is a comment - that is, it is unexecuted. If you remove those characters from the lines with code (from `fps` to the `]`), the code appears to execure just fine.

Comment: @Carl Lange Duh! Many thanks! Is there a reason why Mathematica exports in this way? It would make a lot more sense to me to have a file that produces an output.

Comment: Mmm, not that I'm aware of, but I don't use that functionality. Normally I would just copy the code out of the notebook and into a plaintext file by hand. Glad to help!

Comment: @220284 How are you exporting the file? Try changing all the cells you want to export to Initialization cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every line that begins with `(*` and ends with `*)` is a comment - that is, it is unexecuted. If you remove those characters from the lines with code (from `fps` to the `]`), the code appears to execute just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

fps=60;
dur=4;
tmin=0;
tmax = 8*Pi;
A=-0.125;
B=0.003;
name = surface_deformation;
For[i=0,i<=fps*dur,i++,
    t=tmin+(tmax-tmin)/(fps*dur)*i;
    surface=ParametricPlot3D[{-2*x*(Sin[t]*A*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/B]-1)/(x^2+y^2+1),-2*y*(Sin[t]*A*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/B]-1)/(x^2+y^2+1),(x^2+y^2-1)*(Sin[t]*A*Exp[-(x^2+y^2)/B]-1)/(x^2+y^2+1)},{x,-0.2,0.2},{y,-0.2,0.2},PlotRange->{{-0.5,0.5},{-0.5,0.5},{0.8,1.2}},Boxed->False,Axes->False,ImageSize->{640,480},PlotStyle->"BlueGreenYellow"];
    Export["~/Movies/mathematica/"<>ToString[name]<>"/"<>ToString[name]<>"-"<>ToString[i]<>".png",Show[surface],Background->None]
]
```

When I run this using `wolframscript test.wls`, it executes and generates a bunch of images in the expected directory.